# Is it possible to show dynamic text on Grafana, based on the result of a query?

Tags: grafana

I'm building a dashboard to show the values of the parameters of a device. One of the parameters is a numeric error code. Based on this value, I'd like to show instructions about the problem causing the error and how to proceed to solve it.

The error code data is on a Prometheus server and I can query the information on Grafana. However, I did not find a way to use the Text widget to show dynamic content, based on this query. Is it possible?

Thanks!